# Trying to call an appcode function through javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0

Initally i have been using a web method in my website to fill the drop down list is it possible to do the same by creating a .cs file in appcode and calling it through javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of HTTPContext class. It provides static methods to get access to the current page object. Using that you can give RegisterClientScript() which registers a client script to the current page. See the following code.

```
System.Web.UI.Page p = (System.Web.UI.Page)HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler;
p.RegisterClientScriptBlock("JSName", "JSScript");
```